# rounding cells up when the number hits X.60

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I'm making something in excel which calculates my hours I work a week/month, when a number gets to 30.60 (two shifts which when finishing on the half an hour) it calculates it as 30.60*wage=not the right pay.

so far I have `=ROUND(SUM(C6:I6),0)` which rounds up the number, which works fine until I have another day which I work till half an hour then it will just show 16 or so.

[image: The wage template I am working with]

As you can see here, it calculates it fine until I work 7.30 hours on a wednesday, the total shows 23.00 instead of 23.30.

How can this be done.

Thank you.

Comment: `=ROUND(SUM(C6:I6), 2)`

Comment: your problem is with excel understanding of your "hours". When you write 7.30 you mean 7 hours 30 minutes = 7.5 hours. But excel understands that as 7 hours and 30/100 of hour = 18 minutes. The easiest solution would be to use 7,5 for 7 hours 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, changing that now

Comment: I would suggest that you change the cell format of your cells to a `hh:mm` format. You can then use something along the lines of `<total time>*<rate>*24`

Comment: post the solution as answer so it can be off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is with excel understanding of your "hours". When you write 7.30 you mean 7 hours 30 minutes = 7.5 hours. But excel understands that as 7 hours and 30/100 of hour = 18 minutes. The easiest solution would be to use 7,5 for 7 hours 30 minutes.

(for sake of checking the question off the unanswered I copied my comment)

Comment: Or, use `7:30`, which Excel will treat both as a time, and as `0.3125`  (i.e. `7.5 / 24`) - so remember to multiply by 24 to calculate hours.  You can enforce this by setting the "Data Validation" to "Time" with appropriate "Start time" and "End time" values

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `7.5` (Seven-and-a-half-hours) or `7:30` (7 hours, 30 minutes - but remember to multiply this by **24**, since Excel stores this as the fraction of a day, `0.3125`) then you can use `INT` and `MOD`:

```
=INT(C6)+(MOD(C6,1)/0.6)
```

The first part, `INT(c6)` will give you the Integer part (i.e. whole hours) which we don't want to scale/skew.

The second part has 2 stages.  First, `MOD(c6,1)` will give us the Decimal part of the number (i.e. `7.3` will become `0.3`) and the second part is to divide by `0.6` to convert from "fake-minutes" to "fraction-of-real-hour"

Finally, since you want to apply the formula to an array of cells, you *will* need to swap from `SUM` to `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(C6:I6)+(MOD(C6:I6,1)/0.6))
```

But, overall, best option is to use `7:30` and set Data Validation only allow actual Time values in that field.

**{EDIT}** *Of course, this will give your output with `0.5` for 30 minutes.  If you want to reverse back to `0.3` for 30 minutes (although, I can scarcely fathom why) then you need to run the same calculation in reverse:*

```
=INT(SUMPRODUCT(INT(C6:I6)+(MOD(C6:I6,1)/0.6))) + 0.6*MOD(SUMPRODUCT(INT(C6:I6)+(MOD(C6:I6,1)/0.6)),1)
```